# Julia Flux: determine type of layer

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I am new to Julia and I am having trouble determining the type of the layer in the `Flux`'s model. For the purpose of example, imagine that my model is just one neuron:

```
using Flux
m = Chain(Dense(1, 1, sigmoid))
```

I want to iterate my `Chain` and, depending on the type of the layer, make different actions (specifically, I want to add regularization for the `Dense` layers).

I come to Julia from Python, and my first guess was to compare the type of the layer to type of `Dense`. Contrary to my intuition, this gives me `false`:

```
for layer in m
    println(typeof(layer) == typeof(Dense))
end
```

1. Why this does not work in Julia?
2. What is the proper way to make it work of Julia? Of course, I can check if the specific fields of the `struct` (`in`/`out`/`sigmoid` in case of `Dense`) exist for the given layer, but there would be no guarantee that it is not some other layer with analogous fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `layers` property of `m` instead and to check if a value is of a given type use `isa` instead. In summary this should work:

```
for layer in m.layers
    if layer isa Dense
        # do something with dense layer
    else
        # do something else
    end
end
```

EDIT: indeed `m` supports iteration and indexing, which I did not know, so as @darsnack suggested this is enough:

```
for layer in m
    if layer isa Dense
        # do something with dense layer
    else
        # do something else
    end
end
```

---

Now to clarify type checking:

- if you have a value, and you want to check if its type is a subtype of a given type use `isa` as I have above
- if you have two types you want to compare for subtyping use `<:`, so you could have written `typeof(layer) <: Dense`; for types `==` checks are not recommended, see [this warning](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/#Be-careful-with-type-equality-1) in the Julia manual

You can check out [this section](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Operations-on-Types-1) of the  Julia manual to read more about it

Answer (score 2):

Iterating with `for layer in m` should be fine. The reason you get false is because `typeof(Dense) == UnionAll`. You should change your code to:

```
for layer in m
    println(typeof(layer) == Dense))
end
```

A more Julian approach is to dispatch on the layer type like so:

```
function processlayer(layer::Dense)
    # do special thing for dense
end

function processlayer(layer)
    # do other thing for anything else
end

for layer in m
    processlayer(layer)
end
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `typeof(x) == Y` at all. That's what `isa` is for.

Comment: Yeah totally agree, but the other answer already covered that aspect, so I didn't see a need to repeat it. I kept the code the same as the question to point out the source of the error.